# Javascript to PHP PDO to MySQL Query returns empty

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, api, pdo

I am constructing an API with Javascript and for security reasons I switched my PHP database calls over to PDO.

Since doing so, I have had troubles with queries returning empty arrays (NOTE: not MySQL syntax errors). The latest example is this:

```
/*JAVASCRIPT*/
var getSampleEntity = function(params) {
//Returns Object
return $.ajax({ 
    url: URL + 'downloadQuadrat_Organism.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'organismID': params.oid, 'quadratID': params.qid },
    dataType: dataType
});
}
```

Header data sent from browser:

```
/*PACKAGE HEADER INFO*/
Request URL:http://..../downloadQuadrat_Organism.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
...
Form Data:
organismID:3
```

Which is sent to server...

```
/*PHP*/
//Init
$resultset = array();
$quadratID = $_POST['quadratID'];
$organismID = $_POST['organismID'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Quadrat_Organism WHERE organismID = :organismID OR WHERE quadratID = :quadratID';

//Main
try{
    $db = connect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':quadratID', $quadratID);
    $stmt->bindParam(':organismID', $organismID);
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        $resultset[] = $row;

    //Return result in JSON
    $resultset = json_encode($resultset);
    print_r($resultset);

} catch(PDOException $e){
    print 'Error!: '.$e->getMessage().'<br/>';
}//End try catch

$db = null;
```

I expect an array of results in JSON (dummy-data in database should return 5 results), instead I receive [] (empty JSON array).

I believe the issue is at the PHP level, but I cannot identify the issue.

Comment: Is it because $quadratID must be set before being bound to the query?

Comment: What do you mean? You have it set. It's the problem with your query that the answer here points out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have an error in your where Condition MySQL query:

Try this out,  use this

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Quadrat_Organism 
WHERE organismID = :organismID OR quadratID = :quadratID';
```

instead of:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Quadrat_Organism 
WHERE organismID = :organismID OR WHERE quadratID = :quadratID';
```

use only one where in your queries.

Comment: Oh dear, how did that sneak in there...I apologise, usually the error is printed out